# Grape with rails: model name conflict or not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

When I create an API service for my rails app I get a problem. The API is below:

`module API
  class Level < Grape::API
    resources :levels do
      get do
        Level.all
      end
    end
  end
end`

and I also created a model named level

`class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  some methods
end`

when I request the API interface

`` undefined method `all' for API::Level:Class ``

so what should I do, I change the `Level.all` to `::Level.all` it worked,but it's not good for me.

Comment: Thank you for formatting my question,I will pay more attention to that next time!

Comment: Hi @kemingcao, I am having the same problem, do you find any solution?

Comment: I use `::Level.all` to fetch data from DB finally. Maybe you can use another class name inherit from `Grape::API`.

Comment: It works. Just add :: before the models name.

Answer (score 1):

This is [by design](http://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup). You are basically disambiguating the class name.